# The 5-Sylow subgroup of $A_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

How many 5-Sylow subgroups have $A_6$?

---

Let $n_5 $ the number of 5-Sylow subgroups of $A_6$ so by the Third Sylow Theorem
$$\left.\begin{array}{c}
n_5\equiv 1\mod 5\\
n_5\mid 72
\end{array}\right\}\Rightarrow n_5\in\{1,6,36\}$$
I know $n_5=36$, but how can I prove $n_5\neq 1,6$?

Comment: Hint: how many elements of order $5$ live in $A_6$?

Comment: @PranavChinmay  There are 144

Comment: Now write a formula for the number of elements of order $5$ in terms of $n_5$!

Comment: Yes, there are 144. Each of them generates a Sylow 5-subgroup. Is it possible for 144 different elements to generate 1 group, or 6 groups?

Comment: Each $5$-Sylow subgroup has four elements of order $5$

Comment: Thank you all very much